# Updating data frame via function to find continuous best value

Tags: r, function, dataframe, time-series

I have a time series dataset with, let's say in a very simplified version, Time and Price columns.

```
Time    Price
15:30:01    NA
15:30:02    NA
15:30:03    36
15:30:04    38
15:30:05    37.5
15:30:06    NA
15:30:07    NA
15:30:08    37
15:30:09    37.8
15:30:10    39
15:30:11    40
15:30:12    38.5
15:30:13    38
15:30:14    38
```

I am looking to write a function that returns the best price like this:

```
Time    Price   Best Price
15:30:01    NA  36
15:30:02    NA  36
15:30:03    36  36
15:30:04    38  38
15:30:05    37.5    38
15:30:06    NA  38
15:30:07    NA  38
15:30:08    37  38
15:30:09    37.8    38
15:30:10    39  39
15:30:11    40  40
15:30:12    38.5    40
15:30:13    38  40
15:30:14    38  40
```

I tried

```
bbo <- function(price1, price2) {
  currbestprice <- price2
  newbestprice <- ifelse(price1 >= currbestprice, price1, currbestprice)
  currbestprice <- newbestprice
  return(currbestprice)
}
```

Where I would initiate my price2 via na.omit(Price)[1] to get the first non-NA value. I would then like the currbestprice to be continuously updated to always hold the most recent best price. Price1 is simply the price series.

However when I test this:

```
p1 <- c(NA,NA,36,38,37.5,NA,NA,37,37.8,39,40,38.5,38,38)
p2 <- 36
```

`bbo(p1,p2)` returns

```
NA   NA 36.0 38.0 37.5   NA   NA 37.0 37.8 39.0 40.0 38.5 38.0 38.0
```

It does not seem to update my currbestprice. I am stuck an would appreciate any help.

Comment: can you replace NA with 0?

Comment: Sure but that still does not solve the major issue of returning the best price. If I replace NA with 0 I get 36.0 36.0 36.0 38.0 37.5  36.0 36.0 37.0 37.8 39.0 40.0 38.5 38.0 38.0 instead of 36 36 36 38 38 38 38 38 38 39 40 40 40 40

Comment: The first two values should be `NA` or 0 because there is no `Price` until 3rd value? Something like `ave(1:nrow(df), 1:nrow(df), FUN = function(x) max(df$Price[1:x], na.rm = TRUE))` ?

Comment: @RonakShah That is only a partly correct target imo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another base R option with the `cummax`-function:

```
# create a new column 'BestPrice'
df$BestPrice <- df$Price

# replace the first NA with the first non-NA value
df$BestPrice[is.na(df$BestPrice)][1] <- df$BestPrice[!is.na(df$BestPrice)][1]

# relace the remaining NA's with zero
df$BestPrice[is.na(df$BestPrice)] <- 0

# use 'cummax' to replace the values with the best price untill that point
df$BestPrice <- cummax(df$BestPrice)
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df
>        Time Price BestPrice
> 1  15:30:01    NA        36
> 2  15:30:02    NA        36
> 3  15:30:03  36.0        36
> 4  15:30:04  38.0        38
> 5  15:30:05  37.5        38
> 6  15:30:06    NA        38
> 7  15:30:07    NA        38
> 8  15:30:08  37.0        38
> 9  15:30:09  37.8        38
> 10 15:30:10  39.0        39
> 11 15:30:11  40.0        40
> 12 15:30:12  38.5        40
> 13 15:30:13  38.0        40
> 14 15:30:14  38.0        40
> ```

---

Another option is to use `na.locf` with the `fromLast = TRUE`-parameter from the `zoo`-package in combination with `cummax`:

```
library(zoo)
df$BestPrice <- na.locf(df$Price, fromLast = TRUE)
df$BestPrice <- cummax(df$BestPrice)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Was looking to avoid a loop and this does it perfectly. T

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
# simulate some data
data = data.frame(
  time = 1:100,
  price = rpois(1:100, lambda = 10)
);

# add some random NA values to it, as in your data
na_idxs = sample(x = 1:100, size = 30);
data[na_idxs, 2] = NA;

# initialise a value we'll update storing the max price
c_max = 0;

# the vector containing the best prices
best_price = list();

# for every price
for(i in 1:length(x = data$price)){

  # if the current price is NA
  if(is.na(x = data$price[i])){
    # don't update c_max
  } 
  # if the current value exceeds c_max
  else if(data$price[i] > c_max){
    # update c_max to this value
    c_max = data$price[i];
  }
  # given the above is mutually exclusive, the current price must be less than c_max
  # so don't update
  else {
    # don't update c_max
  }

  # add c_max to best_price
  best_price[[i]] = c_max;
}

# add best_price to data by adding the column to the end
data = cbind(data, best_price = unlist(x = best_price));

# output the data

    time price best_price
1      1     8          8
2      2    13         13
3      3     7         13
4      4     7         13
5      5     6         13
6      6    14         14
7      7     6         14
8      8    NA         14
9      9     7         14
10    10    NA         14
11    11     9         14
12    12    11         14
13    13    16         16
14    14    14         16
15    15    14         16
16    16    NA         16
17    17     4         16
18    18    11         16
```

Comment: R is not C and growing objects (e.g. `best_price`) could be very expensive for larger objects and should be avoided. Also, R doesn't need `;` at the end.

Comment: Thanks Roman, I'll adjust it. I'm sorry about the semicolons!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (assuming NA to be 0)

```
df <- read.table(text = "
           15:30:01    NA
           15:30:02    NA
           15:30:03    36
           15:30:04    38
           15:30:05    37.5
           15:30:06    NA
           15:30:07    NA
           15:30:08    37
           15:30:09    37.8
           15:30:10    39
           15:30:11    40
           15:30:12    38.5
           15:30:13    38
           15:30:14    38")

colnames(df) <- c("Time", "Price")

df[which(is.na(df$Price)),"Price"] <- 0
Bestprice = df[which(df$Price > 0)[1],"Price"]

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){

  if(Bestprice < df$Price[i]){
    df$BestPrice[i] <- df$Price[i]
    Bestprice <- df$Price[i]
  } else{
    df$BestPrice[i] <- Bestprice
  }
}

> df
Time Price BestPrice
1  15:30:01   0.0        36
2  15:30:02   0.0        36
3  15:30:03  36.0        36
4  15:30:04  38.0        38
5  15:30:05  37.5        38
6  15:30:06   0.0        38
7  15:30:07   0.0        38
8  15:30:08  37.0        38
9  15:30:09  37.8        38
10 15:30:10  39.0        39
11 15:30:11  40.0        40
12 15:30:12  38.5        40
13 15:30:13  38.0        40
14 15:30:14  38.0        40
```